# How can I query public facebook events using graph API? [updated search]

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, events

I have a question about Fb Graph API and performing search queries.
I'm working on a app that request events and this worked fine using the following query :
search?q=[value]&type=event

But this recently stopped working, probably due to the changes facebook made to the search bar. I tried to find a solution but didn't make any progress. I can query it in facebook : 
https://www.facebook.com/search/events/?q=

So if anybody knows the answer on how to do this in the graph api thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to a current bug

subscribe for more information
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1651850528365772/

[UPDATE !]
this bug has already been assigned
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/916199865137566